# 50% width not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two divs that are 50% the width size of the parent, and next to each other. However, they need to have a 2px border. I am trying to keep it responsive, and keeping to percentage widths.

For some reason, they are not aligned next to each other. Even if I remove the border, they are still not next to one another.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/HrXxr/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tab">First Box</div><div class="tab">Second Box</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .container {
        max-width: 500px;
        overflow: auto;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: orange;
    }
.tab {
    display: inline-box;
    width: 50%;
    backround-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px red inset;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Comment: You have declared "display" twice once as 'inline-box' and again as 'inline-block'. 'inline-box' is not a valid css display type.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the padding, try:

```
padding: 5px 0;
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/HrXxr/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

width, by default, does not factor in border or padding. If you want your width to include those properties, set box-sizing: border-box

Answer (score 0):

Try margin-auto, float and 49% width

Answer (score 0):

`width`, by default, does not factor in `border` or `padding`. If you want your width to include those properties, set `box-sizing: border-box`.

[Here's some documentation on the `box-sizing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). `box-sizing: border-box` is especially useful when mixing absolute values (e.g., `px`) with relative values (e.g., `%`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, it would probably be best if you gave the tabs unique id's so that you could apply `float: left` one tab, and then `float: right` the other.

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe it will help

```
.box1 {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 2% 10px 0
}

.box2 {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 2%
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">First Box</div><div class="box2">Second Box</div> 
</div>
```